# How do I export mongodb html code to html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose, ejs

How do I display an html data piece from mongo db correctly?

Data: [The html was encoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Art9g.png)

What it shows: [Not showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNJsA.png)

Code:

```html
<script defer>
      function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
      
    const description = document.getElementById("descontainer")

    description.innerHTML += decodeHtml('<%= post.post.description %>')
 </script>
```

Comment: You can use a npm package like [Node Html parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser)

Comment: I did not fully understand your question. Do you want to show formatted html in textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure why you put that html on a textarea element.
But if the content is comming from a database that is contain use generated content, then you probele need an html sanitizer like [dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

You will use it like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/2.3.6/purify.min.js" integrity="sha512-DJjvM/U3zCRpzrYboJgg23iLHapWcS2rlo7Ni18Cdv+FMs6b3gUF7hQihztj4uVkHHfUwk7dha97jVzRqUJ7hg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script defer>
   function decodeHtml(html) {
            
      return DOMPurify.sanitize(html);;
   }
          
   const description = document.getElementById("descontainer")

   description.innerHTML += decodeHtml('<%= post.post.description %>')
</script>
```